TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable when using speech_recognition
I am noob, and this is my firts post here.
I'm writing a program, which should recognize speech from audio file (and first transform file from .ogg to .wav).
Here is my code:
import speech_recognition
import pydub


def ogg2wav(filename):
    new_filename = filename.replace('.ogg', '.wav')
    audio = pydub.AudioSegment.from_file(filename)
    audio.export(new_filename, format='wav')
    return new_filename


ogg2wav("audio.ogg")

recognizer = speech_recognition.Recognizer()
with speech_recognition.WavFile('audio.wav') as source:
    wav_audio = recognizer.record(source)
print(recognizer.recognize_whisper(wav_audio, language='ru'))

when I run a program I get an error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Алексей/PycharmProjects/pythonProject1/skillbox_voice_transform.py", line 17, in <module>
    print(recognizer.recognize_whisper(wav_audio, language='ru'))
  File "C:\Users\Алексей\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\speech_recognition\__init__.py", line 1408, in recognize_whisper
    import whisper
  File "C:\Users\Алексей\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\whisper.py", line 69, in <module>
    libc = ctypes.CDLL(libc_name)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 363, in __init__
    if '/' in name or '\\' in name:
TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable

How to fix it?
Thanks
I searched this error in google, but found only general information.
upd
OS Windows 7, Python 3.8,
modules:
pip freeze
aiohttp==3.8.4
aiosignal==1.3.1
async-timeout==4.0.2
attrs==23.1.0
certifi==2023.5.7
cffi==1.16.0
charset-normalizer==3.1.0
colorama==0.4.6
ffmpeg-downloader==0.3.0
ffmpeg-python==0.2.0
ffprobe==0.5
filelock==3.14.0
frozenlist==1.3.3
fsspec==2024.3.1
future==1.0.0
idna==3.4
intel-openmp==2021.4.0
Jinja2==3.1.4
MarkupSafe==2.1.5
mkl==2021.4.0
mpmath==1.3.0
multidict==6.0.4
networkx==3.1
numpy==1.24.4
openai==0.27.7
packaging==24.0
platformdirs==4.2.1
pycparser==2.22
pydub==0.25.1
pyTelegramBotAPI==4.17.0
requests==2.31.0
six==1.16.0
soundfile==0.12.1
SpeechRecognition==3.10.4
sympy==1.12
tbb==2021.12.0
telebot==0.0.5
torch==2.2.1
tqdm==4.65.0
typing_extensions==4.11.0
urllib3==2.0.2
vk==3.0
vk-api==11.9.9
whisper==1.1.10
yarl==1.9.2

upd
I tried to run this code on Windows 10 and python 3.12, here's what I got:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\root\Downloads\pythonProject1\skillbox_voice_transform.py", line 17, in <module>
    print(recognizer.recognize_whisper(wav_audio, language='ru'))
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\root\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python312\site-packages\speech_recognition\__init__.py", line 1407, in recognize_whisper
    import torch
  File "C:\Users\root\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python312\site-packages\torch\__init__.py", line 141, in <module>
    raise err
OSError: [WinError 126] The specified module could not be found. Error loading "C:\Users\root\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python312\site-packages\torch\lib\shm.dll" or one of its dependencies.

What is wrong in that case? I surely did run -pip install torch.
Thanks for all comments.

Weird, this error is happening from import whisper. Something might be wrong with your installation. Maybe inconsistent or incompatible versions of some packages?

Wild guess, but maybe re-running pip install whisper or pip install SpeechRecognition will fix the dependencies for you? https://pypi.org/project/SpeechRecognition/ has a long troubleshooting section, you'll probably want to read through it all.

We will need more information, anyway: your OS, your exact python version and your package versions. Maybe add the output of pip freeze to your question?

I reinstalled whisper and speechrecognition, it didn't help. I added info about my system in question.

Windows 7 is 15 years old.   It's possible some things just don't work any more.

tried to run this code on Win10, got another kind of error)

In general, you have None where something iterable is expected. You need to find out where and why.

Regarding your Windows 10 output, pytorch can be challenging to install, so I would recommend you go to https://pytorch.org/get-started/locally/ and chose the options that match your configuration and cut and paste the command the site will construct for you in the box towards the top of the page.
